# Parameter value in table

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have hard coded values in one of the table

[image]

And I am passing this column as a parameter and try to delete some values .The below is mentioned querie:

```sql
DELETE FROM [S4].[@{pipeline().parameters.DESTINATION_TABLE_NAME}] WHERE ERDAT >='@{item().LastLoadDate}' OR @{pipeline().parameters.WHERE_SQL} >='@{item().LastLoadDate}
```

I am getting error :

> ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'Incorrect syntax near '>'.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Incorrect syntax near '>'.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=102,Class=15,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=15,Number=102,State=1,Message=Incorrect syntax near '>'.,},],'

Please advise.

Regards
Rohit

Answer (score 0):

- As shown in the image, the `where_sql` column also has null values. When you try to use one of these values in the query, the error occurs.
- The following is a demonstration where I have a table with `where_sql` column. I used a look up activity to get these values.

[image]

- Now, I used for each to iterate through this result. Inside for each I have used a script activity with following script:

```
delete  from demo where idt>='2023-04-01'  or @{item().where_sql}>='2023-04-01'
```

- When I execute this script, it gives the required result. But when there is null value, the query gives the same error.

[image]

- You can see what query is getting executed in this scenario. The following is an image for reference.

[image]

- So, try filtering out the rows where `where_sql` column value is null thus leaving you with the required column names to query with.